# How can I set gradle resolutionStrategy for only the release build?

Tags: android, gradle, groovy

I'm developing an android app where I want the release build to fail if there is a dependency version conflict. If I want to enable it for *all* builds, I can do this:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy  {
        failOnVersionConflict()
    }
}
```

However I don't want to enable it for debug builds. I can't find any documentation on how to do that. I've tried:

```
configurations.each {
    if (it.name.startsWith("release")) {
        it.resolutionStrategy {
            failOnVersionConflict()
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't apply. I've even tried what I thought would be the equivalent of the first example - but this has no effect:

```
configurations.each {
    it.resolutionStrategy {
        failOnVersionConflict()
    }
}
```

I'm simply switching `.all` for `.each` here, but `failOnVersionConflict` doesn't apply even though the code is executed.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

It should work in the following way:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

configurations.compile.resolutionStrategy {
  failOnVersionConflict()
}

repositories {
  mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:23.0'
  compile 'com.google.guava:guava:22.0'
}

task deps(type: Copy) {
  from configurations.compile
  into('deps')
}
```

When you run `gradle deps` then it should fail with version conflict. If you comment out configuration block guava version 23.0 will be copied.